# Cumulative dice sum with bonus rolls whenever max face appears

Tags: probability, dice

What is the chance of rolling x n-sided dice and getting a sum of at least y, if whenever a die comes up n, one more die is rolled?

I have a high-school understanding of statistics plus whatever experience I gathered playing with math but I honestly don't even know how to begin approaching this problem.

Thank you in advance for your time!

Comment: You should be more clear... when you begin, how many dice do you roll?  $1$ die?  Multiple dice?  Do the bonus dice that get rolled when an $n$ occurs also have the ability to proc additional bonus dice?  Are you interested in the probability of $x$ dice total (*including the bonus dice*) being rolled or is $x$ the initial number of dice rolls before any bonus dice are thrown?

Comment: x is the initial number of dice rolled, not including additional ones. Yes, additional dice can also proc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume six-sided dice here.

Each die is independent, so we can work out the distribution for a single die, and get everything we need from that.

To start, just for fun, we can note that the expected value $E$ when rolling a single die satisfies 
$$ E = \frac{1}{6} 1 +\frac{1}{6} 2 + \frac{1}{6} 3 + \frac{1}{6} 4 +
\frac{1}{6} 5 + \frac{1}{6}(6+E)$$
and so $E=4.2$.

Anyway, the first thing we might notice is that the probability of getting a score of $6m+k$, for any non-negative $m$, and $k \in \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ is
$$
P(6m+k)= \left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^{m+1}
$$
Note that it is not possible to score a multiple of $6$.

We can create some generating functions.  For scores congruent to $1$ mod $6$, we have
$$
\frac{1}{6} x + \frac{1}{6^2} x^7 + \frac{1}{6^3}x^{13} + \cdots
= \frac{x}{6-x^6}
$$
The generating function for congruence class $k$ mod $6$ is $x^k$ times this, so the overall generating function for a single die is
$$
\frac{x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5}{6-x^6} = \frac{x^6-x}{(x-1)(6-x^6)}
$$
So, when rolling $r$ dice, the generating function for the sum is
$$
\left( \frac{x^6-x}{(x-1)(6-x^6)}\right)^r.
$$
Here's an example of how to calculate with this.  Suppose we roll $5$ six-sided dice, and want to know the probability that the sum will be greater than $20$.  We calculate the probability that the sum will be *less than* $20$ by truncating the generating function for a single die and raising it to the fifth power.
Let $$ Q=
\frac{1}{6} x
 + \frac{1}{6} x^2
 + \frac{1}{6} x^3
 + \frac{1}{6} x^4
 + \frac{1}{6} x^5
 + \frac{1}{36} x^7
 + \frac{1}{36} x^8
 + \frac{1}{36} x^9
 + \frac{1}{36} x^{10}
 + \frac{1}{36} x^{11}
 + \frac{1}{216} x^{13}
 + \frac{1}{216} x^{14}
 + \frac{1}{216} x^{15}
+ \frac{1}{216} x^{16}
+\frac{1}{216} x^{17}
+\frac{1}{1296} x^{19}
$$
Then, raising $Q$ to the fifth power, we have
$$
 \frac{1}{7776} x^5
 + \frac{5}{7776} x^6
 + \frac{5}{2592} x^7
 + \frac{35}{7776} x^8
 + \frac{35}{3888} x^9
 + \frac{121}{7776} x^{10}
 + \frac{1115}{46656} x^{11}
 + \frac{1555}{46656} x^{12}
 + \frac{665}{15552} x^{13}
 + \frac{2365}{46656} x^{14}
 + \frac{659}{11664} x^{15}
 + \frac{2795}{46656} x^{16}
 + \frac{5695}{93312} x^{17}
 + \frac{5635}{93312} x^{18}
+ \frac{5495}{93312} x^{19}+\cdots $$
Summing the coefficients of $Q^5$ up to $x^{19}$ gives us
$$
\frac{44711}{93312},
$$
the probability that we score less than $20$ when rolling $5$ dice.  And so, the probability that we score $20$ or more is
$$ 1-\frac{44711}{93312} = \frac{48601}{93312}.$$

Comment: First of all, thank you a lot for taking the time to explain this to me. I am not fully grasping all the concepts:

Comment: You're welcome! Where can I help with further explanation?

Comment: I was not aware of generating functions and I've been trying to understand the concept through Wikipedia. As far as I understand it, generating functions are the framework of other functions and they are always expressed as a Sum. So I a have hard time understanding the meaning and usefulness of the concept in this application. Most of all, I cannot understand how the generating function results in Q.

When Q is raised to the fifth, shouldn't x^2 become x^10, X^19 become X^95, etc? I suppose I am missing something here. (X^n)^m = X^(n*m) right?

Comment: Generating functions are sums, yes.  In this case they are power series, which are like polynomials of infinite degree.  Raising a polynomial to a power is not as simple as raising each term to that power.  For instance, $(x+y)^2=x^2+2xy+y^2$: it is not equal to $x^2+y^2$.  The usefulness of all this is illustrated by the calculation at the end, where I show you how to find the probability that the sum will be 20 or more when using 5 dice, using generating functions. Cheers!

Comment: Alright, I think I am getting it. So, Q is practically constant for a six sided die. In the generating function, if I substitute all 6's with any other natural, it will work for that many sides of a dice? If I raise Q to the 7nth power and then sum the coefficients up to X^30, I'll have the probability of scoring less than 30 with 7 dice?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Also, if you feel my answer was helpful, please consider upvoting and/or accepting it.  Cheers!

Comment: Thank you a lot, your answer was very enlightening!